# Changing the Look and Feel changes the color of JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, colors, look-and-feel, nimbus

I had a `JTextPane` had a differen background and foreground color.Now when the L&F is changed to Nimbus L&F, my `JTextPane` 's color is changed.How come?Only this class is having such problem.While others works well.What is the problem?

This is how i change L&F :

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : 

javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PlayBackVoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PlayBackVoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PlayBackVoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(PlayBackVoice.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

On the other hand, the color changed very well before setting this L&F.
Or these statements were working well:

```
     jtp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
     jtp.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing components delegate their look and feel to `ComponentUI` objects. As part of Swing, there are interfaces defined for each component: `ButtonUI` which `JButton` delegates to, `LabelUI` for `JLabel`, `TextUI` for `JTextPane`, etc.

Each Swing look and feel contains implementations for each of those interfaces. eg. `MetalButtonUI`, `MetalLabelUI`, etc. which paint that component however the look and feel wants to.

When you call `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` it swaps in that set of implementations.

All very clever, but the annoying thing is that each look and feel doesn't have to honour any of your foreground / background / border, etc. settings.

Luckily, Nimbus defines all of its colours as UIManager keys.

So, you can do this sort of thing to override its default colours:

```
UIManager.put("nimbusBase", Color.BLACK);
```

See here for full list:

http://www.ce.unipr.it/people/poggi/teaching/docs/javaSE7.0Tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html

**Update**

Although, saying that, it doesn't look like Nimbus plays nicely at all!
Some people have had some luck overriding Nimbus colours with this:

```
Color bgColor = new Color("99999");
UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
defaults.put("EditorPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", bgColor);
jeditorpane.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
jeditorpane.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", true);
jeditorpane.setBackground(bgColor);
```

Comment: Ahh that update was helpful +1..worked.Thaks for your efforts.:)
But one more thing.This stuff i need not to follow for my other classes...don't know why for this one?

Comment: By not playing nicely, is Nimbus ignoring `UIResource`. Essentially because Swing is so messy there is an attempt to see whether it was a PL&F that set a property. This is done by having the value also implement the `UIResource` marker interface if it is from a PL&F. There are convenience classes such as `UIColor` which extends `Color` and implements `UIResource`. Obviously this doesn't work for the likes of `boolean`, `String`, `enum`s or carefully written value types.

Answer (score 3):

This is slight update to Mr Spoon's update. Actually the code

```
defaults.put("EditorPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", bgColor);
```

is wrong as the second parameter of put call shoud be an object implementing Painter interface.

The correct sequence of code (with Nimbus LAF selected) is

```
UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
defaults.put("TextPane[Enabled].backgroundPainter", 
    new javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter() {

        @Override
        protected AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext getPaintContext() {
            return new AbstractRegionPainter.PaintContext(null, null, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPaint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c, 
                int width, int height, Object[] extendedCacheKeys) {
            g.setColor(bgColor);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        }
    });
jtxtPane.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
jtxtPane.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
```

Comment: Just got this working, but I didn't need to put anything in the paint method.  The bgColor isn't available anyway.  Not sure if it makes a difference.