# Override Swing look and feel for a single component

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm writing a plugin for a Swing application which I don't own or have access to the source code for.  In parts of my UI, I want to use specific colors in order to match my icons.

In this case, I want to create a `JPanel` with a specific background color.

```
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(new Color(101, 102, 103));
```

It appears that no matter what color I use, I get the same result.  I suspect it's the look and feel that is changing the color on me.

All of the solutions I've found discuss changing the look and feel or setting new defaults.  I don't want to take this approach because:

1. It's very dependent on the current look and feel
2. It would affect all panels in the application, and not just the one I'm interested in

The application supports several different themes (look and feels), so even if I were to use the `UIManager` to figure out exactly what they are, this would break as soon as they added a new theme.

I'm not too experienced with Swing, but I feel like the look and feel should set the defaults, but anything I set manually should still take effect.  Is there any way to set the panel's background to a specific color regardless of the look and feel?

Comment: Might be far fetched, but have you tried putting your `JPanel` instance you have created in another `JPanel`, then return this new panel? Maybe this other application is forcing a specific background color to the container you are returning. Wrapping your "real" panel in a dummy wrapper panel might fix your problem.

Comment: Had you tried using `panel.setOpaque(true)` before setting the `background` ?

Comment: This panel is already a child component of the panel I'm handing to the application.  No luck with `setOpaque` either.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. Many times, just creating the `SSCCE` will reveal the problem.

Comment: @splungebob I can't demonstrate the problem with code alone.  If I stick this panel in a `JFrame` in a separate application, it works fine.  The problem occurs when I run as a plugin in a proprietary application which I'm unable to share.

Comment: @zmb 1. LaF has sometimes own rulles, code ordering is very important, same as where, when a how is SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Component); called 2. I can't demonstrate the problem with code alone. quite your issue == agreed with splungebob

Answer (score 1):

I'm chalking this up to a bug (or maybe a feature) in the application's custom look and feel.  If I load a new look and feel the panel is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you could create a custom JPanel that overrides paintComponent(Graphics g) to draw the background color.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the problem while using Nimbus Look-and-Feel. Then please check my answer for more or less same problem at

[Changing the Look and Feel changes the color of JTextPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228336/changing-the-look-and-feel-changes-the-color-of-jtextpane/18999718#18999718)